# Test accuracy cannot improve when learning ZFNet on ILSVRC12

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, imagenet

I've implemented a home-brewed ZFNet ([prototxt](https://gist.github.com/stoneyang/d9f636ab78ee325db51b2822e71f4011)) for my research. After 20k iterations with the definition, the test accuracy stays at ~0.001 (i.e., 1/1000), the test loss at ~6.9, and training loss at ~6.9, which seems that the net keeps playing guessing games among the 1k classes. I've thoroughly checked the whole definition and tried to change some of the hyper-parameters to start a new training, but of no avail, same results' shown on the screen....

Could anyone show me some light? Thanks in advance!

---

The hyper-parameters in the prototxt are derived from the paper [1]. All the inputs and outputs of the layers seems correct as Fig. 3 in the paper suggests.

The tweaks are:

- `crop`-s of the input for both training and testing are set to `225` instead of `224` as discussed in #33;
- one-pixel zero paddings for `conv3`, `conv4`, and `conv5` to make the sizes of the blobs consistent [1];
- filler types for all learnable layers changed from `constant` in [1] to `gaussian` with `std: 0.01`;
- `weight_decay`: changing from `0.0005` to `0.00025` as suggested by @sergeyk in PR #33;

[1] Zeiler, M. and Fergus, R. Visualizing and Understanding Convolutional Networks, ECCV 2014.

and for the poor part..., I pasted it [here](http://pastebin.com/hCXBAfwm)

Comment: Thanks for the formatting! @Shai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions:

1. Change initialization from `gauss` to `xavier`.
2. Work with [`"PReLU"`](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852) acitvations, instead of `"ReLU"`. once your net converges you can finetune to remove them.
3. Try reducing `base_lr` by an order of magnitude (or even two orders).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will change the params to launch new experiments and feedback will be added then. @Shai

Comment: Just dropping `base_lr` from `0.01` to `0.001`, `accuracy` was improved to above `0.47` after about 122k iterations. I will return to report the final results after 700k iterations. @Shai

Comment: I raised `base_lr` from `0.001` to `0.005`, ie, just a half of the `base_lr` in  my initial settings, the test accuracy is `60.x %` after `700k` iterations, which is nearly 3 points higher than Caffenet or AlexNet replicated in official caffe. One of your suggestions saved my day and the rest may be helpful in generic training tasks. @Shai